# When erasing in a new 2D frame one of the layers stays from previous and gets erased for both frames

Tags: animation, keyframes, grease-pencil, 2d, layers

I've been working on a 2D animation in grease pencil and was using two separate layers so I could move and copy only specific pieces from each frame to the next.

So far I had been copying each frame and just moving lines or erasing and it was working just fine locking whatever layer I didn't want to be touched.

For the frame I am now working on it was an entirely different scene so I didn't copy any of the the previous frames but instead moved the node the amount of spaces I wanted and began to draw. One layer disappeared as I expected but another layer is still on top of the new work.

I tried to just erase the lines in that layer but, when looking back at the previous frame, the same lines that the new frame had copied were also erased.

I tried changing the layers but nothing happened and now I'm confused if either of my layers are even separate any more.

I have some ideas now after typing this that I will try but I would like to know how to fix the issue future preference.